# Equality between an expression with $\sin x$ and $e^{it}$

Tags: complex-numbers, harmonic-analysis, dirichlet-series

I define Dirichlet's kernel in the following way:
$$D_N(t) = \sum \limits_{k = -N}^{N} e^{2 \pi i kt}.$$
I managed to show that:
$$D_N(t) = \sum \limits_{k = -N}^{N} e^{2 \pi i kt} = e^{-2 \pi i Nt} \sum \limits_{k = 0}^{2N} e^{2 \pi i kt} = e^{-2 \pi i Nt} \frac{e^{2 \pi i (2N+1)t} -1}{e^{2 \pi it} -1}.$$
My task was however to show that:
$$D_N(t) = \frac{\sin \big(\pi(2N + 1)t \big)}{\sin(\pi t)}.$$
The equality must be quite trivial but I've spent some pages with no result. I would appreciate any hints or tips.

Comment: $$\sin x = {e^{ix} - e^{-ix} \over 2i}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost done. Just multiply numerator and denominator additionally by $e^{-\pi i t} $ and use $e^{i x} -e^{-i x}=2i\sin x $.